# How to write a nested test case in postman?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase, postman-mocks

For Example, if below is my response:

```
{
    "rule":"1001",
    "fixedResponse":"101JOB0011102JOB0012"
}
```

Based on `fixedResponse` field value, can I create a test case like a function within a function for each job validation?

```
pm.test("Validate Resposne"),function(){
    if(pm.response.json().fixedResponse.inculde("101JOB"))
        pm.test("101 JOB vlaidaiton"),function(){
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, what's the purpose of the test case within a test? What are you actually trying to assert against?

Comment: Let say, I have 1st check the presence of  String and if the string is present then I would need to split it and check for split value base on a request filed passed.

Comment: Why do you need a test inside a test to do that? Write a test to check the value is present and then write another one to check the value.